# Google Chrome Cookies - Broken for Virtual Hosts?

Tags: javascript, cookies, coldfusion, google-chrome

I recently moved my development environment to my local machine (mac), and setup an Apache virtual host: dev-mysite so in the browser it's: http://dev-mysite/

No .com or anything like that

issue I'm having now is that signing into the site requires setting a cookie and for some reason Google Chrome isn't letting my dev enviroment instance set a browser cookie where it does work in Firefox, safari etc...

Is this something about Google Chrome or Virtual hosts? Something I should know about?

Thanks.

Comment: It would be interesting to see if setting the cookie domain to `.dev-mysite` would make it work. (mind the dot at the start.) Slim chances, though...

Comment: If it works in Safari, it should work in Chrome. Have you changed any cookie settings? Does it work when you browse in Incognito mode? 
Try doing a cfdump of "COOKIE" to see what the issue could be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding a dot (.) to the hostname - I'm assuming you're using a host file entry to point dev-mysite to 127.0.0.1 - you can use dev.mysite instead. If the hostname doesn't look like a TLD, Chrome may not be accepting the cookie.